# Router operating system run program when new device connects

Tags: linux, python, operating-system

I want to monitor my network and do some actions (e.g. send an email) every time a new device shows up in the network. Which operating system/api would make this job the easiest. I was looking at OpenWRT and Tomato but am open for other suggestions. Obviously this can likely be done with any operating system but as I have very little experience with network engineering I would appreciate it if there was a very simple way to do this. Preferably I would like to write my scripts in something like python but that's only a secondary requirement.

Comment: For "any linux" you can use `arpwatch`, which sends email when new devices arrive or arp records change.

Comment: I want to do more sophisticated stuff than email so can I use arpwatch to call another process?

Comment: in different systems `arpwatch` may differ. In Debian it supports `-s <program>` to specify sendmail program. It can be used for custom tasks instead of sending email. Also `arpwatch` logs it's data via `syslog`. Not sure this is a good way though.

Comment: However, if `fail2ban` is an option for you to perform custom tasks, logging via `syslog` may be the solution.